# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Tags: python-3.x

I've been doing some previous research about this error. There are some explanations here in StackOverflow related, the solutions suggested are quite unrelated though.

When I try to import Gtk from gi.repository, it crashes with the following output:


    `bash-4.2$ python3
    Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 21 2011, 21:11:06) 
    [GCC 4.6.0 20110212 (Red Hat 4.6.0-0.7)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/importer.py", line 76, in load_module  
dynamic_module._load()
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 251, in _load
overrides_modules = __import__('gi.overrides', fromlist=[self._namespace])
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 400, in <module>
class MessageDialog(Gtk.MessageDialog, Dialog):
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 404, in   
MessageDialog
type=Gtk.MessageType.INFO,
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 127, in __getattr__
ascii_upper_trans = string.maketrans(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

Since this is an import straight from python console and not by executing a python file script I don't even have a clue how to handle this.

Comment: it seems your importing a python 2 module with python 3 as `string.maketrans` is absent in python 3

Answer (score 25):

Ok, I managed to get it work. Despite is a dirty workaround:

I modified `/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/module.py`

in line 127 I replaced `string.maketrans` with `str.maketrans` so it complies with python 3 docs.

Hope to be helpful for anyone in my circumstances.

Hugo

Comment: please simplify your question as something like how to translate `string.maketrans` in python3 and accept your answer, again simplified as "replace `string.maketrans` with `str.maketran`".

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to run `string.maketrans` using Jupyter notebook and it the error message:

> the module string has no attribute maketrans.

Changing the code to `str.maketrans` did the trick. It must be noted however that I did not have to make any changes to the:

```
/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/module.py
```

Comment: I am unable to find the dir of `module.py` on Win 8.1 for python 3.7? @Stats_Lover

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a known bug [bug737375](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=737375) and it was fixed (almost like Hugo own solution).

You can find the fix in the master branch of the pygopbject repository here:
http://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/commit/?id=8f89ff24fcac627ce15ca93038711fded1a7c5ed

Anyway I'll rewrite here what's in the diff, so maybe I'll save you some time :)

From the file: `/usr/lib64/python3.2/site-packages/gi/module.py`

You should replace:

```
import string
```

with:

```
try:
    maketrans = ''.maketrans
except AttributeError:
    # fallback for Python 2
    from string import maketrans
```

And again replace (around line 130):

```
ascii_upper_trans = string.maketrans(
```

with:

```
ascii_upper_trans = maketrans(
```

Comment: This is the exact solution necessary, unfortunately.  Thanks.

Comment: That's what I got when I tried to import.     

 from string import maketrans
ImportError: cannot import name 'maketrans'

Answer (score 3):

## Just replace `string.maketrans` with `str.maketrans`

*As said by [Искрен Станиславов](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2848256/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2) in a answer below.*