# Can no Longer open Spyder IDE for Python Programming

Tags: python, spyder

I installed Python 3.4 on my Windows 7 laptop several months ago as part of Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads). My installation included the Spyder IDE, and I have successfully been using Spyder for Python programming.

However, since yesterday, I have been unable to open Spyder. I typically open Spyder via the Start Menu, but now, when I try to click on the Spyder icon in the Start Menu, I get no response. I then tried to go directly to the spyder.exe file in the Scripts folder in the directory where Anaconda is installed. When I clicked on this the first time, the following message flashed quickly and then disappeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py". line 2, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py", line 114, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 100 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\qt\QtSvg.py", line 10 in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtSvg import * # analysis:ignore
ImportError:DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

I double-clicked on Spyder.exe a second time, and this time, received the following message:

```
kfile.py", line 146 in lock
    symlinke(str(os.getpid()), self.name)
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\external\lockfile.py", line 87, in symlink
    os.rmdir(newlinkname)
OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty: 'C:\\Users\\Aniket\\.spyder2-py3\\spyder.lock.1459432906109.newlink'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py". line 2, in <module>
    start_app.main()
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py", line 106, in main
    from spyderlib import spyder
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 100 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Aniket\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\qt\QtSvg.py", line 10 in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtSvg import * # analysis:ignore
ImportError:DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Both of these messages flashed very quickly and then disappeared - I captured them by quickly pressing Print Screen when they appeared. It's not evident to me what the error messages imply, nor what would have caused this. It's possible that I closed Spyder while some function was running, or that Spyder crashed and caused some persistent error. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Never heard of Spyder, but have you looked at PyScripter?

Comment: Nope, but I'll check it out. I'm probably going to look for a new IDE in the meantime while I try to get Spyder working.

Comment: I installed PyScripter. The Start Menu gives 3 options for PyScripter: 1) Pyscripter for Python 2.7 2) Pyscripter for Python 3.4 3) Pyscripter for Latest Python Version. The first and third open properly. The second gives me the following error message: Error 193: Could not Open Dll "python34.dll", and then "Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit"

Comment: Sounds like something's borked in your Python 3.4 install, then.  At this point I would try uninstalling and reinstalling Python 3.4.

Comment: For a good python IDE, checkout PyCharm. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue. The following worked for me
Please close Spyder IDE, in Anaconda Prompt run

```
conda update spyder
```

then

```
spyder --reset
```

Restart Spyder

Comment: Under my case, I was able to get the spyder IDE launched again by running `conda update spyder` without `spyder --reset`.

Comment: I tried just updating it but got the same problem, after I reset it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem of Spyder 2 not starting. My installation is part of Anaconda, on Win7 64-bit OS. I tried all the solutions outlined here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747158/python-spyder-reset/40310266#40310266), but they did not work for me. From the command line, I got the following error(s) when trying to reset spyder:

```
U:\>python -c "from spyderlib.spyder import main; main()" --reset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\pApps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\qt\__init__.py", line 48, in <module> from PySide import __version__  # analysis:ignore
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\pApps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\requirements.py", line 40, in check_qt from spyderlib import qt File "C:\Temp\pApps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\qt\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Spyder requires PySide or PyQt to be installed")
ImportError: Spyder requires PySide or PyQt to be installed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Temp\pApps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py", line 48, in <module> requirements.check_qt()
  File "C:\Temp\pApps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\requirements.py", line 50, in check_qt % (qt_infos['pyqt']+qt_infos['pyside']))
  File "C:\Temp\pApps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\requirements.py", line 25, in show_warning
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Please check Spyder installation requirements:
PyQt4 4.6+ (or PySide 1.2.0+) is required.
```

What surprised me was that spyder worked fine till yesterday, and I just did a full update yesterday as follows:

```
conda update --all
```

So I again updated spyder today with the following:

```
conda update spyder
```

And the following package plan was presented to me:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

        spyder:     2.3.7-py35_3      None://None/<unknown> --> 2.3.8-py35_1
        spyder-app: 2.3.7-py35_0                            --> 2.3.8-py35_0

    The following packages will be DOWNGRADED due to dependency conflicts:

        matplotlib: 1.5.3-np111py35_1                       --> 1.5.1-np111py35_0
        pyqt:       5.6.0-py35_0                            --> 4.11.4-py35_7
        qt:         5.6.0-vc14_0                            [vc14] --> 4.8.7-vc14_9
         [vc14]
        qtconsole:  4.2.1-py35_2                            --> 4.2.1-py35_0
```

After the update, spyder works fine now.
In essence, my problem was due to dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same exact problem as you a few days ago and reinstalling won't work so I went to:

```
C:\Users\'YourName'\\.spyder2-py3
```

delete every spyder, lock file/folder in it and relaunch.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but having just had the same problem an answer that worked for me from https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3005

My problem appeared to be that the status of spyder  was still running so wouldn't open. To fix this you need to look for a directory called  .spyder2  in your  Users\  directory, then find a file called  spyder.lock  and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1. I uninstalled Anaconda spyder
2. Removed all directories of it from
   c: programs/
   and c:users/Username/
   and c:users/username/AppData/local
   and c:users/username/AppData/
3. I downloaded a newer version of Anaconda Spyder and installed it.
   It's all fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You might get additional information if you run

```
from spyder.app import start
start.main()
```

as a python script. For example I got following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python_env\workspace\TechDiff\src\demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from spyder.app import start
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 24, in <module>
    from spyder.config.base import get_conf_path, running_in_mac_app
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    from spyder.utils import encoding
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\encoding.py", line 23, in <module>
    from spyder.py3compat import (is_string, to_text_string, is_binary_string,
  File "C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\py3compat.py", line 77, in <module>
    from collections import MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (C:\python_env\App\WinPython\python-3.10.1.amd64\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

=> Maybe for Python 3.10 the import of collections needs to be fixed.
=> Try to use 3.9

Comment: Spyder have lots of various issues. I found this solution works better as a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same error messages before, and I fixed it by installing spyder again under anaconda:

```
conda install spyder
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it says it is missing PyQt4.dll, which you can check by: searching pyqt4 in your anaconda3 directory.
There are several possibilities:

- it is still in: ~\Anaconda3_x86\Library\plugins\designer

That would mean python can't find since it ain't searching in this directory, I highly doubt that possiblity, since that would mean you'd have tweaked some code.

- it ain't anywhere

Maybe you or more likely one of your programs did deleted it per accident?

- it isnt in: ~\Anaconda3_x86\Library\plugins\designer

I also doubt this possibilty since it would mean the file has been moved...

However you can fix that by reinstalling spyder as mentioned by xuwei.