# Can not handle "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'"

Tags: python, module

to learn the argparse module, I have copied some code from the official documentation site.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print (args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

But when I type

```
python argparseTesting.py
```

in the command-line, then the following error appears:

```
test
case
with
strings
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
At Index 0 of our array, we have pens
At Index 1 of our array, we have staplers
At Index 2 of our array, we have flame-throwers
At Index 3 of our array, we have binders
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "optparser_short.py", line 1, in <module>
    import argparse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    import textwrap as _textwrap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 40, in <module>
    class TextWrapper:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 82, in TextWrapper
    whitespace_trans = string.maketrans(_whitespace, ' ' * len(_whitespace))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

In [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628306/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-maketrans) , I read nearly the same question. But the advices there do not help. I have the python version 2.7.11.

I hope someone can help.

best regards,

Comment: You have a local file named `string.py`. Rename it.

Comment: Rename it , ok , but to what ? To maketrans.py ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as it is not the same name as a built-in module you want to use.

Comment: I renamed it but have still the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost certainly have a local Python file named `string.py` in your Python module search path. It is masking the standard `string` library.

Find it by adding:

```
import string; print(string.__file__)
```

to your `argparseTesting.py` script, run it exactly like you ran it before, and then rename or delete any file `string.py` files printed by that line that not located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`. Don't forget to clean up the `string.pyc` file that'll be located next to it. You may have to do this more than once, depending on how many locations on your `sys.path` have such a file. **Don't do this to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/string.py`**, that is the library version.

It doesn't matter much what you name it instead; the point is that Python should *not* find it under the name `string`. It should find the standard library module instead.

Do be sure to run that in the same context as your `argparseTesting.py` script; the first place Python looks for extra modules is the *same directory as your script*, but if you don't run your script then you could be running different code from a different directory and not see that file being imported.

There are two other possibilities here, but these would apply only if the above shows the path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/string.py` or `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/string.pyc`. In that case either something has *edited* that file (you'll need to restore it, the 2.7.11 version is located [in the Python code repository](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Lib/string.py)), or some other code has deleted that name from the `string` module with `del string.maketrans`. Such code would have to be run through the [`site`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site) or [`user`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/user.html) config hooks.

Comment: I did it, but the same error is still there. I renamed the string.py to s.py, then I deleted the string.pyc. But the same error appears.

Comment: @user3097712: what does `import string; print(string.__file__)` show now?

Comment: it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "str.py", line 1, in <module>
    import string 
ImportError: No module named string

Comment: @user3097712: so what file did you delete before, what path was that?

Comment: At the beginning, the short script what you wrote gave me 'string.py', I changed it to s.py. Then I delete 'string.pyc'. These two files were both in /usr/local/lib/python2.7

Comment: @user3097712: right, that was the wrong file. Rename `s.py` back to `string.py`. But you said the error in your post still happens, so you are running that script *in a different context*. The current working directory must be different in that case, because you still have a `string.py` file *there*. I've updated my instructions to make sure you catch the right one.

Comment: okay, thx...it worked now. I undo all steps, and copy my script into the python2.7 file. Run it and it worked . thanks

Comment: remove string.pyc as well